# Random Forest Accuracy

Tags: r, random-forest

I am using Random forest algorithm to predict target variable "Y" have 4 values 
Below syntax is used to create model

```
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=2, repeats=1, search="random")
seed <- 7
metric <- "Accuracy"
set.seed(seed)
mtry <- sqrt(ncol(train))
model <- train(Target~., data=complete, method="rf", metric=metric, tuneLength=15, trControl=control)
```

But, when I test trained model on test dataset it does gives accuracy close to 50% only , is there any way in which accuracy can be increased close 70% and above?

Comment: If its random, then keep running it again and again, you'll get 70% or above on a run surely :)

Comment: I don't know this API, but you can try increasing the number of trees in the forest or decreasing the node size (the number of observations above which the tree will keep splitting).

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, Thanks for suggestion, I increased number of trees till 2001 and accuracy increased by 5%, is there any way to identify exact number of trees needs to use which can increase accuracy?

Comment: It really depends on the data, the model, etc.  When adding more trees no longer gives an improvement, stop adding more trees.